# ¿Como darle estilo css a pagina html?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>chilaquiles</title>

         </head>
    
    <body>
        
         <h1>Prepara los mejores chilaquiles </h1>
         
        <p ALIGN="justify"> Nada mejor para curar la cruda, desayunar en familia o sentirnos bien mexicanos que unos buenos chilaquiles para el desayuno.</p>
        <p ALIGN="justify">Este platillo puede ser muy fácil de preparar y con un poco de imaginación les quedará delicioso. Además, es de los desayunos que pueden multiplicarse fácilmente (un poco más de salsa, un poco más de totopos y caben más personas en la mesa.</p>
       
         <img src="https://cdn2.cocinadelirante.com/sites/default/files/styles/gallerie/public/images/2017/06/chilaquilesrojosbajosengrasa.jpg" alt="">
        
         <h2>Ingredientes</h2>
         <ul>
             <li> 10 tortillas cortadas en tiritas, doradas en suficiente aceite (O una bolsa de totopos ya fritos)</li>
             <li>½ litro de agua</li>
             <li>3 jitomates</li>
             <li>7 chiles serranos (o más si quieren que pique de verdad)</li>
             <li>¼ de cebolla</li>
             <li>3 dientes de ajo</li>
             <li>Caldo de pollo</li>
             <li>Sal y pimienta al gusto</li>
             <li>Queso manchego, crema y cebolla picadita para acompañar</li>     
        
        </ul>
        
         <h2>Preparación</h2>
        
        <ol>
            <li>Para la salsa: El chiste de unos buenos chilaquiles reside en el sazón de la salsa, así que aquí es donde se vale jugar con su imaginación.<br> Hierve el agua y coloca los jitomates dentro durante 30 segundos, sólo para que se afloje la piel. <br>Pélalos y luego regrésalos al agua y déjalos hervir junto con los chiles.</li>
            <li>Cuando estén blandos coloca todo en la licuadora y agrega la cebolla y los dientes de ajo. Licúa bien. A mí en lo personal me gustan las salsas más espesas, pero todo depende del gusto de quien cocina, así que puedes agregar o quitar agua según tu gusto.</li>
            <li>En un sartén caliente sofríe la salsa en un poco de aceite y sazona con sal, pimienta y caldo de pollo. Cuando la salsa esté hirviendo agrega los totopos. Para que los chilaquiles crujan debes retirar todo del fuego y servir rápidamente; si los prefieres blanditos déjalos remojando un poco más de tiempo en la salsa</li>
           
        
        
        
        </ol>
       
        </body>
   
</html>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. En esta página damos respuestas a preguntas y problemas especifícos, así que trata de que los títulos de tus preguntas sean lo más específicas posible. Para dar estilo se usa CSS, colocando la etiqueta <style> //Tu estilo </style> en el head, o en un archivo .css y añadiendolo con <link href="archivo.css". En internet hay mucha información sobre cómo usar css, solo es cuestión de buscar y cuando te encuentres con problemas, vienes a preguntar (siempre que no hayas encontrado solución en Internet).

Comment: También puedes añadir el atributo style="//Tu estilo" a cada etiqueta siempre que quieres que el estilo afecte solamente a esa etiqueta.

Comment: Hola @MelvinTorres ya has dado pasos de aprender `HTML` de la misma forma debes tener interés de investigar, en YouTube existe un sin números de tutoriales, sobre los estilos `CSS`, entre intermedio básicos y avanzados.

Comment: Por favor revisa [ask] y trata de mejorar tu título de pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que agregar una etiqueta style en el head de tu archivo html, o si quieres puedes hacer referencia a un archivo css colocando este tag en el head, `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="(ruta de archivo css)">`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>chilaquiles</title>

        <style> //se abre el tag de estilos
            body { // el selector css de un elemento en el documento html
                background-color: black; // cambia el color de fondo
                color: white; // cambia el color de las letras
        </style

     </head>

    <body>

         Aquí mi texto con fondo negro y letras blancas

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes mandar a llamar un archivo css colocando el siguiente codigo dentro de la etiqueta head `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="(ruta de archivo css)">`.

A la vez algo basico es colocar clases y/o id's en los elementos de tu html de esta forma

`<body>
  <p class="destacado">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p> <!--Para una clase-->
  <p id="destacado2">Nunc sed lacus et est adipiscing accumsan...</p> <!--Para un id-->
  <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora...</p>
</body>`

Y manejarlos en el CSS asi:

`.destacado{
    color: blue; 
}
 #destacado2{
    color: #00B9E0;
}`

La principal diferencia entre este tipo de selector y el selector de clase tiene que ver con HTML y no con CSS. En una misma página, el valor del atributo id debe ser único, de forma que dos elementos diferentes no pueden tener el mismo valor de id. Sin embargo, el atributo class no es obligatorio que sea único, de forma que muchos elementos HTML diferentes pueden compartir el mismo valor para su atributo class.

De esta forma, la recomendación general es la de utilizar el selector de ID cuando se quiere aplicar un estilo a un solo elemento específico de la página y utilizar el selector de clase cuando se quiere aplicar un estilo a varios elementos diferentes de la página HTML.